# Confused about off session payment flow for Invoices

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe to process off session payments. Basically my customer saves their default payment method on their Express customer portal. They make a bid on an item and if the bid is accepted, which could be some days later, an off session payment is made. I got this to work find using Payment Intents, however receipts aren't shown on the customer portal unless they are Invoices.

How do I set up the same flow using the Invoices API? I've tried this flow, but the payment intent that is created reports as requires_confirmation.

1. Create an Invoice
   [create-invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbE4K.png)
2. Create an Invoice Item
   [invoice-item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjGFl.png)
3. Finalize an Invoice
   [finalize-invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvCzI.png)

Is there maybe some point in the process that I can manually create a payment intent, which currently does work for me off session?

Comment: Those steps should have processed the payment automatically, as long as you aren't setting `auto_advance` to `false` when creating or finalizing the Invoice (your screenshots seem to indicate you aren't). I would suggest double checking the state of the Invoice and Payment Intent to see if they did progress through their lifecycles as expected.

Comment: I just checked and it does look like it processed, it took about an hour after I submitted the invoice before the payment intent that was created went through processing. Is that normal? Would I have to manually confirm the payment intent if I went everything done as soon as the invoice is created?

Comment: If you were testing this in test mode, then that delay may be expected. I would be surprised if you saw a similar delay in live mode. I avoid interacting with lower-level objects that are created by higher-order ones (other than things like updating `metadata`) to avoid risking impacting Stripe's flows.

Comment: I'm getting the same delay in live mode. Honestly I'm not too worried about the delay, I'm just worried I'm doing something wrong with the workflow